# User define function which picks values from previous sheet not updating

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a `prevSheet()` function in my excel sheets. Whenever I copy and paste the template sheet into a new sheet, that function is working. Later I created `Addworksheets()` function through VBA, that copies a template sheet into a new sheet, rename it & locks it. From then that `prevSheet()` function not updating. Everytime i have to select the cell & press enter to get it updated though calculating options set to `Automatic`.

Can some one has any help for this please ?

**This is my addworksheet() function:**

```
Sub AddWorksheet() Application.Volatile

Dim i As Integer 
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

If ThisWorkbook.ProtectStructure = False Then


Dim dateString As String, TheDate As Date Dim valid As Boolean: valid
= True

Do   dateString = InputBox("Enter the first date of the month for which you want to prepare the sheet", "Enter The Date", Day(Now()) & "/" & Month(Now()) & "/" & Year(Now()))
     If dateString = "" Then

    MsgBox "You cancelled the action of creating new sheets.  If you want to create new sheets for the month, it is manndatory to enter the date to detect the month and number of days of the month"
    Exit Sub
       Else
    If IsDate(dateString) Then
        TheDate = DateValue(dateString)
        valid = True
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid date"
        valid = False
    End If
         End If    
Loop Until valid = True

Dim mon As Integer 
Dim yea As Integer 
Dim days As Integer


mon = Month(TheDate) 
yea = Year(TheDate)

days = Day(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(TheDate, 0))

Dim date1 As Date date1 = DateValue("1-" + mon + 1 & "-" & yea)



For i = 1 To 31

'# if to check if sheets already exists If Not sheetExists(32 - i) Then Set ws1 = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets("DEBTORS"))


If 32 - i <= days Then Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Cells.Copy ws1.Cells(1, 1) End If

ws1.NAME = 32 - i

If i = 31 Then Worksheets("1").Range("$f$44").Value = date1 End If

ws1.Protect 32 - i, True, True End If ' # end of if that checks if sheet already exisits


Next


Else MsgBox "Please Remove Protection on your workbook structure to add sheets" & Chr(10) & "Review Tab => Protect Workbook" End If


End Sub




Function sheetExists(sheetToFind As String) As Boolean
    sheetExists = False
    For Each Sheet In Worksheets
        If sheetToFind = Sheet.NAME Then
            sheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next Sheet End Function
```

**This is my prevsheet() function:**

```
Function PrevSheet(RCELL As Range)


    'Application.Volatile

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim s As String
    i = RCELL.Cells(1).Parent.Index
    s = RCELL.Cells(1).Parent.NAME

    If s = "1" Then
    PrevSheet = 0

    Else

    PrevSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i - 1).Range(RCELL.Address)

    End If


End Function
```

Comment: Show your code, as it is now one can only guess.

Comment: Dear Hannu, please check, I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem. By adding `Appliction.volatile` to my user defined function which is now forcing it update every time something or some cell is updated.

The commented line in my prevSheet() function code solved the problem.